# Create Dummy Population for Sampling

Tags: python, function, random, statistics, sampling

I have to create a function that generates a population of 5,000 individuals and returns the mean and standard deviation of how many times per day they pick-up their phone. Later in the assignment, I'll have to use this dummy data to extract a sample of 30 individuals, though I need help with the first part before I can move on to the sampling. Here is the given test code that gave me a hint on how to start:

```
pop_pickups, pop_mean, pop_std = get_population(45, 5000, 42)
assert np.abs(pop_mean - 45) < 0.5, "Get population problem, testing pop_mean, population mean returned does not match expected population mean"
assert np.abs(pop_std - np.sqrt(45)) < 0.5, "Get population problem, testing pop_std, population standard deviation returned does not match expected standard deviation"
```

I have the idea that the function will look something like:

```
def get_population(pickups, pop_size, std):
```

and that I may need to use the np.random.randint method to start, but I am really not sure where to go from there or if that's correct. I'm not clear on how to assign a random number to a fake sample (e.g. number of pickups per individual).

Comment: ``np.random.randint(0, max_pickups, 5000)`` where ``max_pickups`` is the maximum number of times someone can pickup their phone (e.g., 100).

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how I might generate a pop_mean or pop_std for this population?

Comment: You can use ``np.mean`` and ``np.std`` to get the mean and standard deviation of an array.

Comment: @Kefeng91 This is what I tried and I got an Assertion Error that the mean was incorrect.
`def get_population(pickups, pop_size, std):
    pop = np.random.randint(0, pickups, 5000)
    mean = np.mean(pop)
    std = np.std(pop)
    return pop, mean, std`

Comment: What's the assertion error you get?

Comment: I figured it out. Had to use Poisson distribution